# Phonegap 3.3.0 File Remove Success function not called

Tags: javascript, function, file, cordova, delete-file

I'm trying to delete the files that aren't in the "files" object.
When I check after the execution, the files are removed but still the alert doesn't show up. (I use alert because I didn't manage to enable the console...)

```
var reader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
reader.readEntries(function(entries) {
    for(var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        var found = false;
        for(var j in files) {
            if(entries[i].name == fileName(files[j]['localPath'])) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            alert('deleting : '+entries[i].name); // called
            try {
                entries[i].remove(function(){
                    alert('deleted : '+entries[i].name); // not called
                }, function(e){
                    alert('delete failed : '+e); // not called
                });
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e); // not called
            }
        }
    }
}, null);
```

Any hints on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone get the same problem, I found out why it wasn't working.
I try to print "entries[i].name" in the success callback but it doesn't exist anymore, so an error shows up and nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to `fileSystem.root.getFile(entries[i].name, {create: false}, delFileEntry, fail);`

and then call

```
function delFileEntry(fileEntry){
  fileEntry.remove(successDel, failDel);
}
```